# API response design in Open API 3.0

Tags: api, rest, openapi

I am designing an API which is a GET endpoint which will return JSON response
Am confused on a few points:
#1  From this example from swagger :

```
/store/order/{orderId}:
get:
  tags:
  - "store"
  summary: "Find purchase order by ID"
  description: "For valid response try integer IDs with value >= 1 and <= 10."
  operationId: "getOrderById"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  responses:
    "200":
      description: "successful operation"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Order"
```

Now what does 'schema' in above example mean ?
Look I am aware of schema w.r.t validation and used at other places in spec but what is the purpose of 'schema' under response ?
Is it used for any validation or is the term 'schema' simply used to display examples ?
See image below :
[image]

Just confused with what 'schema' means in response ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The schema defines the structure and the format of the response JSON body. Refer [here](https://swagger.io/specification/#schema-object) for its documentation.

It is mainly used for the displaying purpose in the swagger UI (see the image below) such that users can know the details about the response JSON structure such as the data type of each field , and if a field is an enum , what is the available value for that enum etc.

[image]